# ant time format backslash issue

Tags: date, ant, properties-file

I have an ant build.xml to create/modify a version.properties file with the following tag:

```
<propertyfile
            file="${version.file}" comment="Build version info">
            <entry key="buildDate" type="date" value="now" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

The the result is this:

```
buildDate=01-28-2015 15\:49\:57
```

Is there a way to eliminate these back slashes in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`propertyfile` uses a `java.util.Properties` object to store properties in a file. From the documentation of [`Properties#store()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29):

> For the key, all space characters are written with a preceding \ character. For the element, leading space characters, but not embedded or trailing space characters, are written with a preceding \ character. **The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.**

So you don't have to worry about the backslashes - they will be ignored in case the properties file is read back in your buildfile. If you absolutely must remove the backslashes for a certain reason, you would need to parse the file and manually remove them (e.g. using some sort of a regular expression).